# How to create array with many normalized float values in python

Tags: python

In Python, if I have a data `[1,2,...,9,10]`, I can use `range(1,11)` to simplify the code. However, how to simplify the code of the normalized version of those data in Python? For instance, now I have the data `[(1-1)/(10-1),(2-1)/(10-1),...,(10-1)/(10-1)]`. The results must be in float type.

Comment: What about using list comprehension: `[(x-1)/(10-1) for x in range(1,11)]`?

Comment: `m = 10   l = [x/(m-1) for x in range(m)]`

Comment: @toti08 The result is integer, how to make the results as float values?

Comment: What about `[(x-1)/9. for x in range(1,11)]`? Or casting the result to float: `[float((x-1)/(10-1)) for x in range(1,11)]`

Comment: In Python 3 result is float, in Python 2 you have to cast to float or just premultiply by float constant 1.0  (`/ is floor division when both args are int`)

Comment: Thanks @MBo, it works.

Comment: Thanks @toti08, it works

Comment: You may want to think about using NumPy here: `numpy.linspace(0, 1, 10)` is cleaner (less code), possibly faster, and NumPy was made for handling arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simplify more, you can wrap the second line in a function.

```
_range = range(1, 11)
_n_range = [(x - min(_range)) / (max(_range) - min(_range)) for x in _range]
```

Comment: The result is in integer, right? It should be float.

Comment: As @MBo mentioned in the comments, results are `float` in python3 and `integer` in python2. You can try the code below for `float` results in python2.

```_n_range = [float((x - min(_range))) / float((max(_range) - min(_range))) for x in _range]```